# netflix on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, netflix

So I have got Ubuntu 12.04 on a system 76 lemur ultra laptop.

I installed netflix via terminal with the following chain of commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

when it was finished installing, I clicked the icon and something came up asking if you want to install some dependent software, but wouldn't let me interact with the window - so I hit tab and worked my way through that. But my computer shutdown before I could fully install GECKO.

Now I have the netflix icon, but when i click it or right click it nothing happens. I had tried uninstalling it with the following commands,

```
sudo apt-add --purge remove netflix-desktop
```

and then reinstalling it but there's no change.

does anyone know what I can do to get netflix to run from here? or what I can do to start troubleshooting? I searched around on AskUbuntu but couldn't find any answers to this specific problem.

Comment: what was the output of `sudo apt-add --purge remove netflix-desktop` command?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Gecko and reinstalling it.  Then try installing your netflix app.  If gecko isn't fully installed then that's probably why things don't work the dependencies aren't there.